# How do I resolve conflicts in TFS?

Tags: version-control, tfs, conflict

How do I resolve conflicts in TFS?

I must have forgotten to do a recursive get before editing a file.  Whatever the cause is, I must now figure out how to resolve a conflict.

When I click on the workspace to performa check-in.  One of the files as a two-way pointing arrow which I guess must mean there is a conflect.

When I click to perform a "Check In" a message box appears that tells me:
  "No files checked in due to conflicting changes.  Please use Conflicts Channel to resolve conflicts and try again".

So I googled "Conflicts Channel TFS" and I got some results but all of the results only gave suggestions, like, Click on "Automatic Resolve".  The problem is that I do not see any of the menu commands or buttons to ckick on that they suggest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try getting latest on the file. That should trigger the conflict resolution screen.

Answer (score 11):

Open the View menu in Visual Studio from the main tool bar. Scroll down to 'Other Windows', then open the 'Pending Changes' window.

On the right side of this Pending Changes window, there are 5 Buttons, each with an icon.  The 5th one down is the Conflicts button. This will show you all the conflicts and will allow you to resolve them here.